# вызов функции без названия

Tags: c++, драйвер, kernel

```
HANDLE thread_handle = nullptr;
const auto status = (
    &thread_handle,
    GENERIC_ALL,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    server_thread,
    nullptr
);
```

Что за функция тут вызывается?Что это за стиль такой?

Полная функция:

```
extern "C" NTSTATUS DriverEntry(
PDRIVER_OBJECT  driver_object,
PUNICODE_STRING registry_path
)
{
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(driver_object);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(registry_path);

HANDLE thread_handle = nullptr;
const auto status = (
    &thread_handle,
    GENERIC_ALL,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    nullptr,
    server_thread,
    nullptr
);

if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    log("Failed to create server thread. Status code: %X.", status);
    clean_unloaded_drivers();
    clean_piddb_cache();
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

ZwClose(thread_handle);
clean_unloaded_drivers();
clean_piddb_cache();
return STATUS_SUCCESS;

}
```

Comment: В си нет auto... Вы что-то путаете .

Comment: ошибся,исправил

Comment: `auto` есть (но с другим значением), а вот `nullptr` точно нет (если только это не определено пользователем)

Comment: Это точно не функция, и не лямбда. И хотя инициализация в Си++ безумна, я не помню чтобы было что-то подобное.

Comment: Ссылку на исходники можно?

Comment: https://github.com/btbd/hwid

Comment: @Whitehorse не смог найти там этого кода. Какой файл?

Comment: @dIm0n kernel\main.c  DriverEntry

Comment: Нет там `auto` в принципе, по вашей ссылке.

Comment: @Whitehorse я проверил по ctrl+f все файлы, включая этот. В `DriverEntry` код не такой, как в вопросе

Comment: @dIm0n прошу прощения,вот https://dropmefiles.com/gnSn6

Comment: возможно тут имеется в виду мифическая недокументированная функция WDM [ZwCreateThread](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a8d4778b0d54da088821971642873ef51)

Comment: @Cerbo ну даже если так , откуда компилятор знает какую туда функцию подставить?

Comment: @Whitehorse Никак не узнает, тут явно ошибка. Harry прав status всегда будет нулль.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По большому счету, никакая, и непонятно, кто и зачем это написал. Если это C++ (в смысле применения `auto` и `nullptr`), то тут срабатывает оператор "запятая", так что в конечном счете получается `status` - переменная типа

```
std::nullptr_t
```

с соответствующим значением `nullptr`.

Откуда вы этот код взяли?...

Comment: это из драйвера,и этот код создает поток server_thread,и он работает...

Comment: Возможно это не Си++, а какая-то его модификация (я с такими не работал, но слышал, вроде для Arduino что-то подобное было, но наверняка не только).